# Power Automate Update Page Content in OneNote

Tags: onenote

I have a table on a page in a OneNote section that I'd like to replace with data from excel. I'm trying to do this via Power Automate's OneNote action "Update page content (Preview). The table includes a title, two rows, and seven columns. It looks like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj4Of.png)

The main issue I have is not being able to target this table because it doesn't provide a div ID I can use for the 'Update Target - 1' line in the flow. **Any help in finding a way to target this table using the proper syntax for this field would be greatly appreciated!**

What I did try is pulling the object id from the link obtained by right-clicking the table container (div) and adding it to the Update Target-1 field. I chopped off everything in that URL besides the object id, shown below, but after running the flow it said I didn't have it in JSON format. The detail view of the content looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "target": "object-id:{9F3EEB37-CA7B-4A06-BA62-588D8D81A53F}",
    "action": "replace",
    "position": "after",
    "content": "dynamic content for each column"
  }
]
```

One last thing: I don't know anything about Microsoft Graph so discussion/answers provided in that context = *wooooosh*